# Install old version of TeX Live – untarring failed

Tags: texlive

To compile some old papers laying around as source, I wanted to install some old version of TeX Live.

I downloaded the install-tl-unx.tar.gz from
ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final

And then run:

```
TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=texlive ./install-tl-20150411/install-tl --repository=ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final
```

But there seems some problem with tar:

```
Installing [0001/3036, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
tar: texlive/2014/temp/12many.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
untar: untarring texlive/2014/temp/12many.tar failed (in texlive/2014/texmf-dist)
untarring texlive/2014/temp/12many.tar failed, stopping install.
Installation failed.
```

Whats happening here? Both the `12many.tar` and the outputdirectory exist.

Comment: Where are you, where is the tar file and where is the output directory? Also, who are you?

Comment: Ah, it seems like TeX Live versions older than 2015 can not handle a relative path as TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX Live versions older than 2015 require an absolute `TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

So this works:

```
export TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/texlive 
./install-tl-20150411/install-tl --repository=ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final
```